# Ember.js starter kit <h2> not rendering

Tags: ember.js

I downloaded the Ember.js starter kit from https://github.com/emberjs/starter-kit

I have not edited any of the files.  Whether I open the included index.html from file or over a server (SimpleHTTPServer), the `h2` "Welcome to Ember.js" does not appear in the browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ember Starter Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    <ul>
    {{#each item in model}}
      <li>{{item}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>

  <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-template-compiler-1.11.0.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-1.11.0.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <!-- to activate the test runner, add the "?test" query string parameter -->
  <script src="tests/runner.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `ul` works perfectly.  Why doesn't the `h2`?

Comment: If I move the <h2> line below {{outlet}}, it does render.

Comment: I can't reproduce it see: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vanasiguho/1/edit

Comment: Is it in the DOM when u check with dev tools?

Comment: this seems related to styles/css

Comment: @blessenm no, and I've tried it in Chrome, FF, and Safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is some regression in Ember 1.11.0. I updated both ember and ember-template-compiler to the latest release and it seems to work. [You can get these from here.](http://emberjs.com/builds/#/release)

[Here is a link to this bug reported.](https://github.com/emberjs/starter-kit/issues/66)